# Sip status (ringing, busy, in use, etc.)

Tags: asterisk, pbx

How can i look on cli sip peer status like ringing, busy, in use, etc. Note that sip peer is not member any queue.

Answer (score 2):

Sip peer status is reachable/unreachable.

What you have asked is device state. Asterisk have multiple method for check device state, for example you can do it via AMI or ARI

https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+13+Devicestates+REST+API

Comment: execuseme i forgot write metod. I want it in cli

Comment: So what is problem? Add it to cli. At this moment cli show only custom states "devstate list"

Comment: Exactly which command return state of sip on cli ?
In my case state mean ringing, busy, hold, etc.

Comment: There is no such command, you can easy add it, source code availible.